# Spring Boot with OpenAPI generate API request never ends on sending ResponseEntity<Resource>()

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have a Spring boot maven project. I generate all my controllers with [openapi-generator maven plugin](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin). For an endpoint i would like to return a file and I have the following yaml conf:

```
/myCustomEndpoint/generateMyZip:
  post:
    tags:
      - ControllerZip
    operationId: generateZip
    requestBody:
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/DocumentsObjects'
      required: true
    responses:
      '200':
        description: Zip with all documentDto in pdf
        content:
          application/octet-stream:
            schema:
              type: string
              format: binary
```

Note: the returning file is a zip built in memory.

I use the DP Delegate and here my ResponseEntity that my delegation return to the Endpoint autogenerate is:

```
ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .contentLength(zipResource.contentLength())
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                        ContentDisposition.attachment()
                                .filename("whatever")
                                .build().toString())
                .body(zipResource);
```

**The issue:** When I try to consume my auto-generated endpoint, I receive a 200 response but I never receive the body and the request eventually times out, as if something wasn't closed.

**Note:** When I use a controller node generated with OpenAPI and with the same signature/interface as the auto generated one, that works and I correctly receive my file (as application/octet-stream).